# Is an IIS-Spawned Process CPU-Limited?

Tags: iis, application-pools, cpu-usage, capacity-planning, multi-threading

Seems more appropriate here than at StackOverflow; we'll see if it gets closed.

Let's say I have an IIS App Pool set to cap at 25%. But the pool runs a webservice which spawns a process. Is that subsequent process subject to a subset of that 25% or does it get full reign of the CPU?  And if so, how can I regulate it to stay within the set limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a full-blown new process, there's no way you can control its CPU allocation; a new thread in the same process would instead be costrained by the same limitations of the process that spawns it.